# JAVA Querying the list of data using Stream filter,null pointer exception

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<Data>data = Datalist.stream()
.filter(o -> o.getX().equals(data.getX()) && 
  o.getY().equals(data.getMwSchemeCode().getY()) && 
  o.getZ().equals(o.getZ()))
.collect(Collectors.toList);
```

When I run this code a Null pointer exception occurs.
I already tried to check the stream entity for null, though it didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more code, NPE can be in many places in your line of code

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace, so it's easier to figure out where the NPE is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying your stream calls to something like this:

```
List<Data> data = datalist.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o.getX()) && o.getX().equals(data.getX()))
        .filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o.getY()) && Objects.nonNull(data.getMwSchemeCode()) && o.getY().equals(data.getMwSchemeCode().getY()))
        .filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o.getZ()) && o.getZ().eqauls(data.getZ()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The good thing about streams is that every stream operation is lazy-evaluated, which means that all operations will be triggered in terminating `.collect(Collectors.toList())` call. Splitting single huge `.filter()` operation to a few smaller ones makes your code much more readable and easier to maintain.

In this case we also make sure that every `.getX()`, `.getY()` and `.getZ()` does not return any `null` to avoid `NullPointerException`.